# How can DC-magnetic fields be produced with the aid of currents?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

How can DC-magnetic fields be produced with the aid of currents? What's a possible theoretical explanation for this, and how does one achieve this in the real world? What are the maximum fields that could be produced this way?

Comment: What is a *DC-magnetic field*? Do you mean *How can magnetic fields be produced with the aid of DC currents*?

Comment: I mean uni-directional magnetic fields: http://www.engineering.com/Ask@/qactid/7/qaqid/5576.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Any conductor carrying DC current produces a unidirectional magnetic field. A brief explanation of the phenomenon is given here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magcur.html

Comment: Do the orbiting electrons in a magnetic material cause infinitesimal magnetic fields, due to their orbiting the nucleus?

Comment: @Kamil: Electrons don't orbit the nuclei in atoms, however they do have a spin and in most cases an orbital angular momentum. In ferromagnets the macroscopic magnetic field is due to unpaired electrons spins.